# Strange behavior: login is required with windows authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I've a ASP.NET MVC 3 project with windows authentication (in web.config), when I access in my machine the login is OK, but when I tried to login using another machine with another user it asks for login and password in the browser.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Permissions issue?  Meaning, does the other user have access rights?

Comment: The problem is: anonymous access is enabled, and the user is not accessing the first page of the system that not require access rights.